# Android Expandable List view with recycler view as child

Tags: android

I am implementing expandable list view but I want the children to be recycler view.
I have looked through the forum but haven't found a solution. Can someone help me a link to the explanation of just help me solve this? I am stranded.

Comment: you can not make recycler view as a child element of expandable listview, u need to look for any third party library depending upon ur requirement.

Comment: Do you know of any third party? A link please if any

Answer (score 0):

I got a way out guys...It is possible to do that. A recycler view can be a child of an expandable list view. Implement it normally just like any other view but it should have its own adapter.